# Download YouTube video in server

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, file-get-contents

I have created a YouTube search engine + download + MP3 convert script. I have used [Jeckman's YouTube Downloader](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/blob/master/getvideo.php) for creating this script. Everything is OK, except, I want to download the video into the server instead it downloading it to my computer. I want to do this because, after it gets download, I shall convert the video to MP3 using FFmpeg.

Is there any way to get the video downloaded in my server instead of my computer?

The download.php contains the following code:

```
<?php
// Check download token
if (empty($_GET['mime']) OR empty($_GET['token']))
{
exit('Invalid download token 8{');
}
// Set operation params
$mime = filter_var($_GET['mime']);
$ext  = str_replace(array('/', 'x-'), '', strstr($mime, '/'));
$url  = base64_decode(filter_var($_GET['token']));
$name = urldecode($_GET['title']). '.' .$ext; 
// Fetch and serve
if ($url)
{
// Generate the server headers
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)
{
    header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Pragma: public');
}
else
{
    header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
}
readfile($url);
exit;
}

// Not found
exit('File not found 8{');
?>
```

Comment: strip out all the header stuff, and change `readfile()` to [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

Comment: @MarcB Nothing happened. Though the file loaded for a few seconds, but no file got stored in my public_html folder, or in any folder in it! Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've found out a solution to store the YouTube file to server. I have removed the header stuff and put `$download_video_file = file_put_contents($file_path, fopen($url, 'r'));` in place of `readfile($url);` and it worked like a magic! ^_^

Here's the complete code:

```
<?php
// Check download token
if (empty($_GET['mime']) OR empty($_GET['token']))
{
exit('Invalid download token 8{');
}
// Set operation params
$mime = filter_var($_GET['mime']);
$ext  = str_replace(array('/', 'x-'), '', strstr($mime, '/'));
$url  = base64_decode(filter_var($_GET['token']));
$name = urldecode($_GET['title']). '.' .$ext; 
// Fetch and serve
if ($url)
{
// Generate the server headers
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)
{/*
    header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Pragma: public');
*/}
else
{/*
    header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
*/}
$download_video_file = file_put_contents($file_path, fopen($url, 'r'));
exit;
}

// Not found
exit('File not found 8{');
?>
```

Comment: Using the above code on a local server (appserv) file is created with 0 bytes. Any tips to make it work locally?