# Youtube video download working fine on localhost but not working on live (Production) server

Tags: php, youtube, phpmyadmin, youtube-api

I am working on a php file, where i can put youtube video url, it gives me the download link,  when i click on that download button on localhost, video starts downloading, but when i put it on live, it does not work.
This is code for button

```
    echo '  ' . '<a href="download.php?mime=' . $avail_formats[$i]['type']   .'&title='. urlencode($my_title) .'&token='.base64_encode($avail_formats[$i]['url']) . '" class="dl"><b>Record MP4</b></a>';
```

Here is the code behind that button download button

```
include_once('config.php');
// Check download token
if (empty($_GET['mime']) OR empty($_GET['token']))
{
  exit('Invalid download token 8{');
}

// Set operation params
$mime = filter_var($_GET['mime']);
$ext  = str_replace(array('/', 'x-'), '', strstr($mime, '/'));
$url  = base64_decode(filter_var($_GET['token']));
$name = urldecode($_GET['title']). '.' .$ext; 

// Fetch and serve
if ($url)
{
$size=get_size($url);
// Generate the server headers
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)
{
    header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Pragma: public');
}
else
{
    header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
}

readfile($url);
exit;
}

// Not found
exit('File not found 8{');
```

It always give me error that **invalid download token**, but on localhost, it works properly. Why it won't work when it is live?

Comment: Check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815438/download-youtube-video-in-server) if it can help you.

Comment: Don't you throw that error yourself in the very beginning of your code? You need to provide additional information! As a first step, however, you should check whether the domain of your production server is whitelisted in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)